# Using rectangles to simulate straight line motion of an object

Tags: java, simulation, motion

I am relatively new to Java and have been trying to simulate the motion of an object (say a car) on a straight path.
I want my object to move in steps in the output, instead of appearing just at the last point of the line.

I have used 2 classes :Veh.java - the vehicle object and SimuFrame.java - to create the simulation environment.

I have referred to some online tutorials for ideas: http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/07/java-video-tutorial-52/   (This simulates the asteroids game. Howeer I want my object to move in a straight line instead of in a random direction)

Please help me understand where I am wrong and what to do next..

Thanks a lot.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Veh extends Rectangle{

    int uLeftX, uLeftY; //upper LH Position for Rectangle
    static int height = 20;
    static int width = 20;
    int[] pathCoords=new int[1000]; 

    int startPosY;  // start position of the objet - anywhere on the left bounday of the frame.
    int goalPosY; // end position of the objet - anywhere on the right boundary of the frame.

//Constructor to Create a new Veh
    public Veh(int startPosY,int goalPosY){ 

    //Create a new rectangle vehicle from super class constructor
    super(0, startPosY, height, width);  

    this.startPosY=startPosY;

    this.goalPosY=goalPosY;

    this.pathCoords = Pathmove();

    }


    //Calculating the 1000 points on the line joining (0,startPosY) and  (goalPosY,999)
        int[] Pathmove(){

//Slope calculation
    float s=(float)(this.goalPosY-this.startPosY)/999;

    pathCoords[0]=this.startPosY;
        System.out.println("First xy pair is: 0," +this.pathCoords[0]);
    for(int m=1; m<1000; m++){
    pathCoords[m]= (int)(m*s)-(int)((m-1)*s)+ pathCoords[m-1];
    }
        return pathCoords;
    }

    //Function to move the Reactangular object along the line using the Y coordinate   values from Pathmove()

    void move(){
    int[] a = (int[])this.pathCoords.clone();
    for (int c=0; c<a.length;c++){
    this.setLocation(c,a[c]);
    }
    } 



}
```

---

This is the code for creating the simulation environment.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SimuFrame extends JFrame{

public static int frameWidth=1000;
public static int frameHeight=1000;

public static void main(String[] args){

new SimuFrame();
}

public SimuFrame(){
this.setSize(frameWidth,frameHeight);
this.setTitle("Path Planning Results");
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

SimuObject SO=new SimuObject();
this.add(SO);
// Used to execute code after a given delay
// The attribute is corePoolSize - the number of threads to keep in 
// the pool, even if they are idle
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor= new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);

executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RepaintTheFrame(this), 0L, 20L,    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 

this.setVisible(true);

}

}

// Class implements the runnable interface
// By creating this thread I want to continually redraw the screen
// while other code continues to execute

class RepaintTheFrame implements Runnable{

SimuFrame theFrame;

public RepaintTheFrame(SimuFrame theFrame){
}

@Override
public void run() {

    theFrame.repaint();
    }

}

class SimuObject extends JComponent{

//Holds every Veh created

public ArrayList<Veh> vehs=new ArrayList<Veh>();

public SimuObject(){

    int startPosY = (int)(Math.random()*999);
    int goalPosY = (int)(Math.random()*999);
    vehs.add(new Veh(startPosY,goalPosY));

}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    // Allows me to make many settings changes in regards to graphics
    Graphics2D graphicSettings = (Graphics2D)g;
    // Draw a background that is as big as the Simu board
    graphicSettings.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    graphicSettings.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    // Set rendering rules
    graphicSettings.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    // Set the drawing color to red
    graphicSettings.setPaint( Color.RED);
    // Cycle through all of the Rock objects
    for(Veh veh : vehs){
        // Move the vehicle
        veh.move();
        graphicSettings.draw(veh);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of problems in your code:

- You have a (swallowed) `NullPointerException` (NPE) in `RepaintTheFrame.run()`, which causes `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate()` to run only once, per [`scheduleAtFixedRate()`'s javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).
- You are moving your car in `JComponent.paint()`.

  In any graphical framework, the repaint will be called automatically by the framework, usually on an OS event, e.g. moving the window, moving the mouse over the window, etc.

  Your `paint()` method should only draw. It should *not* modify your domain model.
- Your move() method always ends up with the vehicle at the end. That's probably not your intent. You probably want your move() method to merely increment the car's position.

Answer (score 1):

Moving from a start value to an end value in steps is called [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation). You want linear interpolation specifically here. Its one of the easiest to grasp.

[This page](http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Interpolation.html) will be of great assistance to you.

Without getting fancy with interpolation, you could just change your move routine like so:

```
int index =0;
void move(){
    //int[] a = (int[])this.pathCoords.clone();
    if(index<this.pathCoords.length)    
        this.setLocation(c,pathCoords[index]);
    index+=1;
}
```

Not sure why you were cloning the array there.  It probably isn't necessary.